# Finite abelian p-group with an element of maximal order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

I want to know, following theorem comes from which book?

**Theorem .** Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group and $a \in G$ has maximum order, then there exists a subgroup $K⊆G$ such that:

$ \langle a\rangle+ K =G$

$\langle a\rangle\cap K =\{e\}$

Comment: You want reference or proof?

Comment: no reference of theorem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finite abelian p-group and an element of maximal order](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705959/finite-abelian-p-group-and-an-element-of-maximal-order)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question (but could probably reasonably be closed anyway).

Comment: This looks very much like a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of theorem that you mentioned has two main steps :
1-Cauchy theorem : If $G$ is a finite group, and $p | |G|$ is a prime, then $G$ has an element of order $p$ .
2-If $G$ is a finite abelian $p-$group and G has a unique subgroup $H$ of order $p$, then $G$ is cyclic .
For reference you can see for example Hungerford's [Agebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387905189) chapter 2  or this [PDF handout](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf).

Comment: thank, can i find this theorem in Huppert?(Endliche gruppen 1)

Comment: thanks, can i find this theorm in huppert?(endliche gruppen 1)

Comment: @mana I don' understand German language , but I think this theorem proved in any books about finite groups and classification of them .

Comment: I know but i couldnt find this, in group theory of suzuki or finite group by gorenstein or similar finite groups

Comment: OK. see An Introduction to Abstract Algebra
By Derek John Scott Robinson page 179.